# JavaScript functions work in <script> tag, but not in external file using with facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

When i try to run any function in external file when using Facebook API it does not work. If i copy the code to the same spot in my html file it works perfectly fine. In this example function checkLoginState would run in external file, but alert only shows up if i put this code inside `<script>` tag.

```
function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
  alert("Hello");
}
```

This is full file:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
      appId      : 'app-id',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.12'
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
};

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function statusChangeCallback(response){
    if (response.status === 'connected'){
        setElements(true);
    } else {
        setElements(false);
    }
}

function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
  addFb();
}

function setElements(isLoggedIn){
    if(isLoggedIn){
        document.getElementById('fbLogIn').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('logOut').style.display = 'block';
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById('fbLogIn').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('logOut').style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function logOut(){
    FB.logout(function(response){
        setElements(false);
    });
}

function addFb(){
    FB.api('/me?fields=name,email', function(response){
        if (response && !response.error){
            var user = response.name;
            var email = response.email; 
            var id = response.id;
            $('#message').load("fbregister.php", {
                    username: user,
                    fb_id: id,
                    email: email
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How and were are you linking your JS file? Can you show us your HTML code?

Comment: have you tried using the defer attribute?

Comment: I link my JS file where my body begins with <script src="facebook.js"></script>

Comment: you get console errors?

Comment: This is also my 3rd javascript file i add in this document after JQuery and another file. I have tried adding defer attribute, problem stays the same.
 <script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
   crossorigin="anonymous">
   </script>
   <script src="script.js" defer> </script>

Comment: No, no errors in console. I can call any function there also

Comment: No function is called in this javascript file except the one that loads fb sdk

Comment: Have to suspect that the `src` attribute is incorrect.

Comment: You are referring explicitly to your function `checkLoginState` first, but then in what you show as the "full file", you are not even calling that function anywhere …?

Comment: also, why call addFb before you even know the login status?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. The function is called on-click

Comment: Then add that click handler inside the `fbAsyncInit` callback - only then you can be sure that the FB object exists and is ready to work.

Answer (score 0):

The external script is loading async. So it may not be loaded when your code runs. You have to put your function call in a callback that happens when the script loads in.

Comment: @luschn the `(function(d, s, id){...}` part of the SDK embed code dynamically creates a script element, so effectively this is async ...

Comment: i thought that we are talking about HIS script, not the js sdk? the callback for the js sdk is there already anyway.

Comment: Right. And even if you try to do it without async, using the async=false attribute on a script tag, I've seen some browsers ignore that. After all, it provides a worse user experience.